# How to instantiate an instance of our dependency graph in Dagger2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am learning `dagger2` dependency injection framework. I loved it how it injects dependency. I read this article https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2 I see there they explained this with the help of two `Modules`.

`AppModule` & `NetModule` are the two `Modules`. Both has constructors, so they instantiate an instance of our dependency graph like this

```
 mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                // list of modules that are part of this component need to be created here too
                .appModule(new AppModule(this)) // This also corresponds to the name of your module: %component_name%Module
                .netModule(new NetModule("https://api.github.com"))
                .build();
```

Suppose I have one more `Modules` which do not have a constructor then how would I initialize it, as other 2 modules need values in the constructor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your third module doesn't need a constructor Dagger2 will automatically add it to component if you list it in `@Component`'s `modules` like this:

```
 @Component(modules = {
     AppModule.class,
     NetModule.class,
     ThirdModule.class // module without constructor
 })
 public interface NetComponent{
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: I am using latest version of dagger, it says  `.appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .netModule(new NetModule(""))` is deprecated

Comment: @Williams This warning is generated in case when Dagger2 can build your module itself. If you class annotated with `@Module` has all it dependencies satisfied (by itself, other module from same component or other component listed as dependency in parent component) and has default or public no-arg constructor Dagger can instantiate module without manual provision (calling `.someModule(new SomeModule()` is redundant).

Comment: In my case, I have one argument constructor in both modules why it is still giving an warning

Comment: If you look at generated code (`DaggerNetComponent` class) you will see some like this in JavaDoc: _This module is declared, but an instance is not used in the component. This method is a no-op. For more, see [link](https://google.github.io/dagger/unused-modules)._

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your third module is TestModule:

you can simply do this:

```
 mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()        
                .appModule(new AppModule(this)) 
                .netModule(new NetModule("https://api.github.com"))
                .testModule(new TestModule())
                .build();
```

Note: here .testModule will give you *deprecated* warning which means that you don't even have to define modules that have no constructors. They are implicitly added to the graph.

Comment: Okay can you help me to make me understand how `dagger2` create dependency graph ?

Comment: You need to google that. There are a lot of tutorials available out there.